# Php Chat Select messages

Tags: php, mysql, chat

I am currently programming a chat system and I already got the messages into my Database (MySql) So my problem is that I dont know how to get these messages out of my Database and to display It.

```
<ol class="chat">
    <li class="other">
        <div class="message">
            <p></p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ol>
```

I want the messages to show in that

Is that a good start to "get the messages from the Database"

```
$query = "SELECT messages, sender FROM `messages`";
```

Thx for all responses!

Ok here is my full PHP code:

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
include '../Datenbank/dbconnect.php';

// if session is not set this will redirect to login page
if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    header("Location: ../login/index.php");
    exit;
}

// select loggedin users detail
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userId=" . $_SESSION['user']);
$userRow = mysql_fetch_array($res);

$error = false;
$sender = $userRow['userName'];

$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'dbtest');

$query = "SELECT messages, sender, timestamp FROM `messages` ORDER BY `timestamp`";

$result = mysql_query($conn ,$query);

echo '<ol class="chat">';

while ($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "
         <li class='other'>
            <div class='message'>
                <p>Message: ".$res['messages']."</p>
                <p>Sender: ".$res['sender']."</p>
                <p>Time: ".$res['timestamp']."</p>
            </div>
        </li>";

    }

    echo '</ol>';

mysql_close($conn);

if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
    $test = true;
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    if (empty($message)) {
        $error = true;
        $messageError = "Please enter your message.";
    }
    if (!$error) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO messages(message,sender) VALUES('$message','$sender')";

        $res = mysql_query($query);

        if ($res) {
            unset($message);
        } else {
            $errTyp2 = "danger";
            $errMSG2 = "Something went wrong, try again later...";
        }
    }
};
?>
```

Dbconnect.php:

```
<?php

error_reporting( ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE );


define('DBHOST', 'localhost');
define('DBUSER', 'root');
define('DBPASS', '');
define('DBNAME', 'dbtest');

$conn = mysql_connect(DBHOST,DBUSER,DBPASS);
$dbcon = mysql_select_db(DBNAME);

if ( !$conn ) {
    die("Connection failed : " . mysql_error());
}

if ( !$dbcon ) {
    die("Database Connection failed : " . mysql_error());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What PHP SQL method are you using? mysql_connect, mysqli_connect, or PDO?
I will give example for mysqli and PDO since mysql_connect is deprecated.

**MySQLi example**

```
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) 
{
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// sql your query
$sql = "SELECT messages, sender FROM messages";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

echo '<ol class="chat">';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
{
    echo "
        <li class='other'>
            <div class='message'>
                <p>Message: ".$row['messages']."</p> <!-- output message -->
                <p>Sender: ".$row['sender']."</p> <!-- output sender name -->
            </div>
        </li>";
}

echo '</ol>';

mysqli_close($conn);
```

**PDO example**

```
try
{
  // create connection
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname",$username,$password);
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT messages, sender FROM messages"); // your sql query
  $stmt->execute();

  echo '<ol class="chat">';

  while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
  {
      echo "
        <li class='other'>
            <div class='message'>
                <p>Message: ".$row['messages']."</p> <!-- output message -->
                <p>Sender: ".$row['sender']."</p> <!-- output sender name -->
            </div>
        </li>";
  }

  echo "</ol>";
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
  echo "Connection Error : " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
```

**Mysql_connect example (WARNING! This method is deprecated in PHP 7)**

```
// create connection
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
// select database
mysql_select_db('DATABASE_NAME');

$sql = "SELECT messages, sender FROM messages"; // your sql query
$result = mysql_query( $sql, $conn ); // retrieve result

if(! $result )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}

echo '<ol class="chat">';

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
   echo "
        <li class='other'>
            <div class='message'>
                <p>Message: ".$row['messages']."</p> <!-- output message -->
                <p>Sender: ".$row['sender']."</p> <!-- output sender name -->
            </div>
        </li>";
} 

echo "</ol>";
mysql_close($conn);
```

Comment: Thx so far I am using mysql_connect but I keep getting this error: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,

Comment: You cannot mix mysql_connect with mysqli_connect.

Comment: I changed it now I get this error:  mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Comment: No. What I means is, in my example code, I'm using Mysqli_connect. So, if you wanted to use that code, you need to change to mysqli_connect, don't use mysql_connect.

Comment: I have updated the answer, to include the Mysql_connect example code since you are using mysql_connect.

Comment: Got it Thx man!! +rep ^^ Sry I am new on Stackoverflow

Comment: Congrats. Glad I could help :)